# Download files from a specific user's drive with google drive api

Tags: api, download, google-api, google-drive-api

Is there a way to download files from a specific google drive, by using the google drive api? Currently i can only read the drive of the google user logged in.

Comment: More information/context required - what sort of environment include potential "public" access information.

Comment: You can only download, what you're allowed to. And that's quite good this way.

Answer (score 1):

Inorder to access data owned by someone on Google drive you need their permission.   You can't just access my files unless I let you.  The most common method for this is oauth2 but you can also use a service account.

Now if I set a file to public you would be able to read it using an API key but I would have to give you the file id.